# how to get values from arraylist to Textbox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, arraylist

```
ArrayList myArrayList = new ArrayList();
for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j <= dt.Columns.Count - 1; j++)
    {
        myArrayList.Add(dt.Rows[i][j].ToString());
    }
}
```

I want to send a mail to all mail id's which I am storing in array list. How to bind that total array list to a `Textbox`.

Comment: Do you want to bind `ArrayList` only or `string` representation of `ArrayList`will also work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, this code may help you

```
foreach(object item in myArrayList)
{
    TextBoxId.Text += item.ToString();
}
```

Or you can forget your arrayList, populate TextBox directly while looping in table.

```
          for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                 {
                     for (int j = 0; j <= dt.Columns.Count - 1; j++)
                     {
                         //myArrayList.Add(dt.Rows[i][j].ToString());
                         TextBoxId.Text += dt.Rows[i][j].ToString();
                     }
                 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList myArrayList = new ArrayList();

for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j <= dt.Columns.Count - 1; j++)
    {
        myArrayList.Add(dt.Rows[i][j].ToString());
    }
}

StringBuilder strb = new StringBuilder();

foreach (var item in myArrayList)
{
    strb.Append(item + ";");
}
```

You can bind a `strb.ToString()` to your text box or instead of creating an `ArrayList` you can directly append email ids from your `DataTable` to `StringBuilder` and bind it to your text box.